# Accessing MetataData API from Communities as community User

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, metadata-api, lightning-community

I am using [MetadataApi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), to get listview Metadata via Apex. if i logged in as System administrator it's working fine and get the data, but when i call same Apex Method from Community as Community user i got exception.

> IO Exception: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://XXXXXX/Soap/m/46.0

i found this [accessing-metadata-api-in-communities](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159179/accessing-metadata-api-in-communities.) after a deep hunt in our forum

but that one is 2 years back solution, so i am still searching is there any new features came up after 2017 to access the MetadataApi as Community user.

**use case**

i need add limit to show the no of records for my listviews in community, unfortunately with `full layout` option in `record list` component doesn't support the no of records limit to show, 
[image]

so this lack of feature made me to develop a custom lightning component and i used `lightning:listview` and then by apex `SOQL` i pulled `list view` developer Names for my `sobject` and then bind to `lightning:select` based on select option  i loading the `lightning:listview` dynamically up to here every thing works fine.

but some of listviews are using  sharing settings like `visible to certain groups` option. but my get `listview` developer name `SOQL` query returns all `listviews` developer names,  some of them doesn't have access for logged in user.

so above lack of feature made me to use `MetadataApi` to get the listview sharing setting Metatadata and then Check Access level of listview. but after all community user is not able to access metatadata API.

is there any other work around for my use case.

Comment: you might try David Reed's suggestion of using a callout w/ Named Credential (with predefined sysad creds) to an apex REST class that in turn does the metadata API callout and returns results back

Comment: @cropredy can you please more elaborate your/david reed suggestion, or provide david suggestion link

Comment: Search for how to run as a different user.  I don't have time right now to find it.

Answer (score 1):

How about using UI Api to get listViews?

`/services/data/v46.0/ui-api/list-records/Account/AllAccounts`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_list_views_md.htm?search_text=list%20view

Comment: thanks pranay, but i need to access the `Sharedto` metadata from `Listview Metadata`. to check logged in user had access for that list view or not? ` UI Api` doesn't give `SharedTo` settings for Listview. let me update my question with exact Use case